# Pin tabs in default web browser on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webbrowser-app

Is it possible to **pin a tab** in the default web browser on Ubuntu Tounch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it seems there is currently no option to pin any tab in the default web browser on Ubuntu Touch. You only can bookmark pages.